# Checking for passed parameters using null - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, typeof

Take an example function here:

```
function a(b){
    console.log(b != null ? 1 : 2);
}
```

That code works fine, by printing 1 if you pass a parameter, and 2 if you don't.

However, JSLint gives me a warning, telling me to instead use strict equalities, i.e `!==`. Regardless of whether a parameter is passed or not, the function will print 1 when using `!==`.

So my question is, what is the best way to check whether a parameter has been passed? I do not want to use `arguments.length`, or in fact use the `arguments` object at all.

I tried using this:

```
function a(b){
    console.log(typeof(b) !== "undefined" ? 1 : 2);
}
```

^ that seemed to work, but is it the best method?

Comment: If you pass `undefined` then you will get a false negative. `arguments.length` (or variants) is the only way to see if the argument was passed.

Comment: @Esailija If it's not the intention of the function to explicitly work with undefined value, this should be okay imo. It's not the functions responsibility to catch every userfault possible.

Comment: @Christoph If you really need to know if an argument was passed then it's not ok. If you just want to know if the argument is empty or whatever, then `!= null` `!== undefined` and so on are all just as fragile and good , there is no bulletproof in that. Prefer `!= null` to check for `undefined` and `null` at the same time.

Comment: @Esailija It doesn't matter if an argument is passed with value `undefined` or no argument at all if the function does not accept undefined values. `null` however indicates that there IS a parameter passed, since it differs from `undefined` which is the case if no param is passed. So I would not check with `!=null`

Comment: That's why I said *if you really need to know* :P Of course it's not normal needing to know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When no argument is passed, `b` is `undefined`, not `null`.  So, the proper way to test for the existence of the argument `b` is this:

```
function a(b){
    console.log(b !== undefined ? 1 : 2);
}
```

`!==` is recommended because null and undefined can be coerced to be equal if you use `==` or `!=`, but using `!==` or `===` will not do type coercion so you can strictly tell if it's `undefined` or not.

Comment: For the completeness, it's possible to get rid of `typeof` inside the function, because we're in the function scope, and `undefined` can't be overwritten here :) In global scope, it's safer to use `typeof(foo) !== "undefined"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the falsy nature of `undefined` (a parameter, which was not passed is in fact `undefined`, not `null`) and just write:

```
(!b)?1:2
```

However this will also be true for `0`, `null` and `""` (falsy values).

If you want to write it the bulletproof way, you can go:

```
typeof(b) === "undefined"
// or thanks to the write protection for undefined in html5
b === undefined
```

Update: thanks to EcmaScript 2015, we now can use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

```
function a(b = 1){
    console.log(b);
}
```

If a parameter is undefined - either ommited or explicitely handed over (here you should use `null` instead) - the default value will be used, all other values remain unchanged (also falsy ones). [Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/su2u63e6/1/)

Comment: BTW if you want to use default values for the variables not passed to the function, you can write sth like `b = b || defaultValue`. It's a common JS idiom for `if(!b){b = defaultValue;}` -- with the same restrictions as above (`!b` is true if `b` is either `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined` or `""`).

Comment: @jakub.g That is a bad idea, since you can never pass `0` or `""` as a parameter this way. When working with default values you should check it the secure way and not use falsy nature.

Comment: That's right. Makes more sense however when the expected parameter should be an object (`b = b || {}`).

Comment: @Keir Simmons i took the liberty to update the answer to recent Ecmascript standards. Feel free to have a look;)